# WCF Service Client is Hijacking My Interface

Tags: wcf

I have 3 assemblies:
FooInterfaces (Class Library)
FooService (WCF Service)
FooTests (Test Application)

In FooInterfaces I have:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFoo
{
   [OperationContract]
   void Bar();
}
```

In FooService.svc I have:

```
public class FooService : IFoo
{
   void Bar() { ... }
}
```

Now in my test harness I want to instantiate this way after adding a service reference to FooService:

```
IFoo foo = new FooService();
```

Problem is, there are two IFoo interfaces! `FooInterfaces.IFoo` and `FooTests.FooServiceReference.IFoo`. The compiler is confused between the two unless I specify, and the two IFoo types aren't convertable.

There is a reference to FooInterfaces in FooTests.

I have other classes that implement IFoo, so I really need one interface of IFoo.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your test harness also have a service reference to your service?

Comment: @chris.house.00 Yes, and "Reuse types" is enabled in the reference settings.

Answer (score 1):

You have two interfaces one in the FooInterfaces namespace and one in the FooTests.FooServiceReference namepsace.  The latter was created for you when you created a reference to the service and is part of the proxy.  To be explicit about the IFoo that you want to use, use the full namespace name. "FooInterfaces.IFoo".

Comment: Alternatively, remove the reference to the FooInterfaces assembly from your test harness, you don't really need it since you have the interface as part of your service proxy.

Comment: I don't want anything to do with the ServiceReference version of IFoo, in fact I'm surprised it was even created again because I already specified the interface. I beed the service reference version to implement FooInterfaces.IFoo. If I try to cast the reference version, I get a runtime exception.

Comment: Regarding your comment about removing FooInterfaces from test harness, I'm using dependency injection in other classes that require the FooInterfaces version